# jquery slideup and bootstrap's alert(shows one time only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have created a message on my site that say's my site is using cookies:

[image: Cookie Popup]

Created with the following code:

```
<div id="cookies" class="container text-center">
    <h3>This site is using cookies.  
        <a id="hide" class="btn btn-info">Ok! No problem.</a>       
    </h3>
</div>
```

So I thought, when someone presses the button the message slides up using jquery. With this code:

```
<script>
$("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#cookies").slideUp(1000);
})

$("#show").click(function() {
    $("#cookies").slideDown(1000);
})
</script>
```

But for some reason there is nothing happening. This is one of my first times with jquery.

Also:

If someone knows it, is it possible to show this message just one time per IP address? And it doesn't shows up after clicking the button?

Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: IMHO don't add that kind of message.. no one cares. Year 2014 and every site is using cookies..

Comment: Try adding a [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) around your JS.

Comment: you've missed the semi-colon on ever event function, have you added the jQuery library? Have you put your script within a document ready function?

Comment: @Hardy I am bounded to an European law to do this.

Comment: Ok, i'm from Finland (EU) and had newer heard of law like that..

Comment: @Hardy here is some information about it: http://www.theeucookielaw.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to `slideUp` an element (`#cookies`) that doesn't appear to be in your HTML snippet you posted. Are you sure it's there?

If you want to show the message only once per IP you can store it in a cookie as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery/1458728#1458728) here.

You can get an IP through JavaScript like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/810461/3351720).

**Update**

"*Can it be because my head and navigation(where the message is part from) are both separate php files that I include into index.php?*"
- No, the files get 'merged' together before they are served to the client / browser.

You are trying to execute your script before jQuery is loaded. If you check your console you see this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. jQuery defines `$` as a shortcut to jQuery and because it isn't loaded yet it's still not defined and causes your script to error.

Put your script below the jQuery include at the bottom of the page. It's always good practice to put all the scripts at the bottom of your page (like the Google Analytics snippet) just before you close the `body`-tag.
This makes sure that your HTML and CSS renders and doesn't get blocked by any JavaScript.

You might wrap your script inside a `ready` handler, to make sure it doesn't get execute before the whole page is ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $("#cookies").slideUp(1000);
    }); // don't forget the semicolon here

    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#cookies").slideDown(1000);
    }); // don't forget the semicolon here
});
```

Also don't forget to open the `body` after you close the `head` and close the `body` and `html` tags at the bottom of your page.

You might also want to take a look at the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for more best practices.

Comment: Can it be because my head and navigation(where the message is part from) are both separate php files that I include into index.php?
(here is the site if you want to take a look: http://mrblackdragonfly.com)

Comment: Updated my answer with what I've seen on your site. If this works for you please accept my answer :)

Comment: Thanks! It was because my code was in my head! Your code worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can manage by jQuery `cookie` plugin, when you load page on browser, check cookie information if the box already loaded there if `yes` then simply hide by `hide()` function.

Cookie jQuery plugin:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    var status = $.cookie('the_cookie');
    if (status == "hide") {
        $('#cookies').hide();
        console.log('the box hided on the IP');
    } else {

    }

    $('#hide').click(function() {
        $('#cookies').slideUp(1000, function() {
            $.cookie('the_cookie', 'hide', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
        });
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvH75/)

Comment: The Fiddle is blocked in Chrome, cross-origin problem.